# Phone number regular expressions

Tags: clojure

Included is some code that can find a single number such as "555-555-5555" in a string. But I'm not quite sure how to extend the code to find all phone numbers within a string. The code stops after it has found the first number...

```
(defn foo [x]
(re-find (re-matcher #"((\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+))" x)))
```

Is there a way to extend this code to find all numbers within a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re-seq` returns a sequence of all the matches to a regex in a string:

```
user> (defn foo [x] (re-seq #"\d+-\d+-\d+" x))                  
#'user/foo 

user> (foo "111-222-3333 555-666-7777")                         
("111-222-3333" "555-666-7777")   

user> (foo "phone 1: 111-222-3333 phone 2: 555-666-7777")       
("111-222-3333" "555-666-7777")
```

So it will keep going until it finds all the phone numbers in the string.

Comment: nice answer, just want to add there are many phone regexps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 0):

I you are interested in searching all possible phone numbers, depending on the region / country code and other parameters, check the phone-number library:

https://github.com/randomseed-io/phone-number

There is a function `find-numbers` for that purpose:

https://randomseed.io/software/phone-number/phone-number.core#var-find-numbers